# Load SVG contained in div using Lightbox2

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox2

How can I display a SVG contained inside a `div` with Lightbox2? In the example below, I would like to load the SVG contained inside the div with the id `testsvg`:

```
<div id="testsvg">
    <svg width="400" height="180">
    <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5"> 
    </svg>
</div>

<a href="#testsvg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Test SVG!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#testsvg + a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 11%;
}
```

```html
<div id="testsvg">
  <svg width="400" height="180">
    <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
  </svg>
</div>

<a href="#testsvg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Test SVG!</a>
```